# Underscore GroupBy A Single Facet Compared Against Nested Object Properties

Tags: javascript, json, knockout.js, underscore.js

Given **[this](http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/?id=ed0db520ebf362972104968b43e26ca5)** JSON result, or seen below:

```js
{
  "facetItems": [{
    "Company_Name": "Sample Brookline Company",
    "Address_Line_1": "242 Oak Boulevard",
    "Address_Line_2": "",
    "City": "Brookline",
    "State": "MA",
    "Latitude": 42.3325651,
    "Longitude": -71.1140136,
    "Company_Type": [{
      "ID": "id2",
      "Display_Value": "A"
    }, {
      "ID": "id4",
      "Display_Value": "B"
    }]
  }, {
    "Company_Name": "Sample Everett Company",
    "Address_Line_1": "242 Oak Boulevard",
    "Address_Line_2": "",
    "City": "Everett",
    "State": "MA",
    "Latitude": 42.4030189,
    "Longitude": -71.0454874,
    "Company_Type": [{
      "ID": "id1",
      "Display_Value": "G"
    }, {
      "ID": "id2",
      "Display_Value": "A"
    }, {
      "ID": "id3",
      "Display_Value": "E"
    }, {
      "ID": "id4",
      "Display_Value": "B"
    }, {
      "ID": "id5",
      "Display_Value": "C"
    }]
  }, {
    "Company_Name": "Sample Wakefield Company 1",
    "Address_Line_1": "242 Oak Boulevard",
    "Address_Line_2": "",
    "City": "Wakefield",
    "State": "MA",
    "Latitude": 42.5091051,
    "Longitude": -71.0675369,
    "Company_Type": [{
      "ID": "id1",
      "Display_Value": "G"
    }, {
      "ID": "id2",
      "Display_Value": "A"
    }, {
      "ID": "id3",
      "Display_Value": "E"
    }, {
      "ID": "id4",
      "Display_Value": "B"
    }, {
      "ID": "id5",
      "Display_Value": "C"
    }]
  }, {
    "Company_Name": "Sample Wakefield Company 2",
    "Address_Line_1": "242 Oak Boulevard",
    "Address_Line_2": "",
    "City": "Wakefield",
    "State": "MA",
    "Latitude": 42.5091059,
    "Longitude": -71.0675379,
    "Company_Type": [{
      "ID": "id1",
      "Display_Value": "G"
    }, {
      "ID": "id2",
      "Display_Value": "A"
    }, {
      "ID": "id3",
      "Display_Value": "E"
    }, {
      "ID": "id4",
      "Display_Value": "B"
    }]
  }, {
    "Company_Name": "Sample Wakefield Company 3",
    "Address_Line_1": "242 Oak Boulevard",
    "Address_Line_2": "",
    "City": "Wakefield",
    "State": "MA",
    "Latitude": 42.5091089,
    "Longitude": -71.0675399,
    "Company_Type": [{
      "ID": "id3",
      "Display_Value": "E"
    }, {
      "ID": "id5",
      "Display_Value": "C"
    }]
  }, {
    "Company_Name": "Sample Wakefield Company 4",
    "Address_Line_1": "242 Oak Boulevard",
    "Address_Line_2": "",
    "City": "Wakefield",
    "State": "MA",
    "Latitude": 42.5091101,
    "Longitude": -71.0675401,
    "Company_Type": [{
      "ID": "id1",
      "Display_Value": "G"
    }, {
      "ID": "id2",
      "Display_Value": "A"
    }, {
      "ID": "id3",
      "Display_Value": "E"
    }]
  }, {
    "Company_Name": "Sample Wakefield Company 5",
    "Address_Line_1": "242 Oak Boulevard",
    "Address_Line_2": "",
    "City": "Wakefield",
    "State": "MA",
    "Latitude": 42.5091131,
    "Longitude": -71.0675431,
    "Company_Type": [{
      "ID": "id3",
      "Display_Value": "E"
    }, {
      "ID": "id4",
      "Display_Value": "B"
    }, {
      "ID": "id5",
      "Display_Value": "C"
    }]
  }, {
    "Company_Name": "Sample Wakefield Company 6",
    "Address_Line_1": "242 Oak Boulevard",
    "Address_Line_2": "",
    "City": "Wakefield",
    "State": "MA",
    "Latitude": 42.5091151,
    "Longitude": -71.0675451,
    "Company_Type": [{
      "ID": "id1",
      "Display_Value": "G"
    }, {
      "ID": "id2",
      "Display_Value": "A"
    }, {
      "ID": "id4",
      "Display_Value": "B"
    }, {
      "ID": "id5",
      "Display_Value": "C"
    }]
  }]
}
```

I would like to group the `facetItems` by the following Collection of Objects `ID` that are returned from a content management system, as this list decides the order:

```
        "Company_Type": [
          { "ID": "id1", "Display_Value": "G" },
          { "ID": "id2", "Display_Value": "A" },
          { "ID": "id3", "Display_Value": "E" },
          { "ID": "id4", "Display_Value": "B" },
          { "ID": "id5", "Display_Value": "C" }
        ]
```

**What the result should look like**

```
{
    "Company_Type": [
      {
        "ID": "id1",
        "Display_Value": "G",
        "Companies": [
            {
                "Hospital_Name": "Sample Brookline Company",
                "Address_Line_1": "242 Oak Boulevard",
                "Address_Line_2": "",
                "City": "Brookline",
                "State": "MA",
                "Latitude": 42.3325651,
                "Longitude": -71.1140136,
                "Company_Type": {}
            },
            {
                "Hospital_Name": "Sample Brookline Company",
                "Address_Line_1": "442 Oak Boulevard",
                "Address_Line_2": "",
                "City": "Brookline",
                "State": "MA",
                "Latitude": 42.1231213,
                "Longitude": -71.5454354,
                "Company_Type": {}
            }
        ]
      },
      {
        "ID": "id2",
        "Display_Value": "A",
        "Companies": [ { "more companies that match this grouping" }]
      }
    ]
}
```

**What I've tried**

Getting the unique `Company_Types` from the `facetItems`:

```
_.chain(self.results()).map(function (f) { return f.Hospital_Type })
    .flatten().uniq(function (f_ht) { return f_ht.ID }).value();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working example

```js
var 
    facetItems = [
        {
            "Company_Name": "Sample Brookline Company",
            "Address_Line_1": "242 Oak Boulevard",
            "Address_Line_2": "",
            "City": "Brookline",
            "State": "MA",
            "Latitude": 42.3325651,
            "Longitude": -71.1140136,
            "Company_Type": [
              {
                "ID": "id2",
                "Display_Value": "A"
              },
              {
                "ID": "id4",
                "Display_Value": "B"
              }
            ]
        },
        {
            "Company_Name": "Sample Everett Company",
            "Address_Line_1": "242 Oak Boulevard",
            "Address_Line_2": "",
            "City": "Everett",
            "State": "MA",
            "Latitude": 42.4030189,
            "Longitude": -71.0454874,
            "Company_Type": [
              {
                "ID": "id1",
                "Display_Value": "G"
              },
              {
                "ID": "id2",
                "Display_Value": "A"
              },
              {
                "ID": "id3",
                "Display_Value": "E"
              },
              {
                "ID": "id4",
                "Display_Value": "B"
              },
              {
                "ID": "id5",
                "Display_Value": "C"
              }
            ]
        },
        {
            "Company_Name": "Sample Wakefield Company 1",
            "Address_Line_1": "242 Oak Boulevard",
            "Address_Line_2": "",
            "City": "Wakefield",
            "State": "MA",
            "Latitude": 42.5091051,
            "Longitude": -71.0675369,
            "Company_Type": [
              {
                "ID": "id1",
                "Display_Value": "G"
              },
              {
                "ID": "id2",
                "Display_Value": "A"
              },
              {
                "ID": "id3",
                "Display_Value": "E"
              },
              {
                "ID": "id4",
                "Display_Value": "B"
              },
              {
                "ID": "id5",
                "Display_Value": "C"
              }
            ]
        },
        {
            "Company_Name": "Sample Wakefield Company 2",
            "Address_Line_1": "242 Oak Boulevard",
            "Address_Line_2": "",
            "City": "Wakefield",
            "State": "MA",
            "Latitude": 42.5091059,
            "Longitude": -71.0675379,
            "Company_Type": [
              {
                "ID": "id1",
                "Display_Value": "G"
              },
              {
                "ID": "id2",
                "Display_Value": "A"
              },
              {
                "ID": "id3",
                "Display_Value": "E"
              },
              {
                "ID": "id4",
                "Display_Value": "B"
              }
            ]
        },
        {
            "Company_Name": "Sample Wakefield Company 3",
            "Address_Line_1": "242 Oak Boulevard",
            "Address_Line_2": "",
            "City": "Wakefield",
            "State": "MA",
            "Latitude": 42.5091089,
            "Longitude": -71.0675399,
            "Company_Type": [
              {
                "ID": "id3",
                "Display_Value": "E"
              },
              {
                "ID": "id5",
                "Display_Value": "C"
              }
            ]
        },
        {
            "Company_Name": "Sample Wakefield Company 4",
            "Address_Line_1": "242 Oak Boulevard",
            "Address_Line_2": "",
            "City": "Wakefield",
            "State": "MA",
            "Latitude": 42.5091101,
            "Longitude": -71.0675401,
            "Company_Type": [
              {
                "ID": "id1",
                "Display_Value": "G"
              },
              {
                "ID": "id2",
                "Display_Value": "A"
              },
              {
                "ID": "id3",
                "Display_Value": "E"
              }
            ]
        },
        {
            "Company_Name": "Sample Wakefield Company 5",
            "Address_Line_1": "242 Oak Boulevard",
            "Address_Line_2": "",
            "City": "Wakefield",
            "State": "MA",
            "Latitude": 42.5091131,
            "Longitude": -71.0675431,
            "Company_Type": [
              {
                "ID": "id3",
                "Display_Value": "E"
              },
              {
                "ID": "id4",
                "Display_Value": "B"
              },
              {
                "ID": "id5",
                "Display_Value": "C"
              }
            ]
        },
        {
            "Company_Name": "Sample Wakefield Company 6",
            "Address_Line_1": "242 Oak Boulevard",
            "Address_Line_2": "",
            "City": "Wakefield",
            "State": "MA",
            "Latitude": 42.5091151,
            "Longitude": -71.0675451,
            "Company_Type": [
              {
                "ID": "id1",
                "Display_Value": "G"
              },
              {
                "ID": "id2",
                "Display_Value": "A"
              },
              {
                "ID": "id4",
                "Display_Value": "B"
              },
              {
                "ID": "id5",
                "Display_Value": "C"
              }
            ]
        }
    ]
;


var companyTypes = [
          { "ID": "id1", "Display_Value": "G" },
          { "ID": "id2", "Display_Value": "A" },
          { "ID": "id3", "Display_Value": "E" },
          { "ID": "id4", "Display_Value": "B" },
          { "ID": "id5", "Display_Value": "C" }
        ]
    
var finalResult = _.map(companyTypes,function(a){
  a.Companies = _.filter(facetItems, function(b){
             return _.findWhere(b.Company_Type,{ID:a.ID});
          });
  return a;
})

document.getElementById('result').innerText = JSON.stringify(finalResult)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
<div id="result">

</div>
```

Basically I'm mapping all Company Types, adding a property Companies to each one and looking for corresponding companies

Comment: I wasn't aware that you could map a new property, thanks